# Why do I get an error installing Ruby 1.8.7-p302 using RVM?

Tags: ruby, xcode, installation, rvm

I get the following error when trying to RVM install 1.8.7-p302:

> ```
>  shawn-taylors-macbook-pro-2:~ shawntaylorphoto$ rvm install 1.8.7-p302
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  ERROR: Error running ' ./configure
> --prefix=/Users/shawntaylorphoto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302
> --enable-shared --disable-install-doc  ', please read
> /Users/shawntaylorphoto/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p302/configure.log ERROR:
> There has been an error while running configure. Halting the
> installation
> ```

I checked the configure.log file as suggested, and get this:

> ```
>  [2011-07-16 14:55:30]  ./configure
> --prefix=/Users/shawntaylorphoto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302
> --enable-shared --disable-install-doc   checking build system type...
> i686-apple-darwin10.7.0 checking host system type...
> i686-apple-darwin10.7.0 checking target system type...
> i686-apple-darwin10.7.0 checking for gcc... no checking for cc... no
> checking for cl.exe... no configure: error: in
> `/Users/shawntaylorphoto/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p302': configure: error:
> no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH See `config.log' for more
> details.
> ```

Is Xcode an acceptable C Compiler? I would think so. I've got it in /Developer, but not in ~/Users/username/... Thinking this is the problem, and if so, can I tell RVM to look there for the C compiler, or is it better to install Xcode in the /user folder?

Alternately, if I'm totally off and neither of these is the problem and solution, any other advice would be hugely appreciated!!!

~~~

As per the Tin Man's instructions, here is

> shawn-taylors-macbook-pro-2:~ shawntaylorphoto$ rvm info
>
> system:
>
> system:
>       uname:       "Darwin shawn-taylors-macbook-pro-2.local 10.7.0
>   Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011;
>   root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386"
>       bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release
>   (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"
>       zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)"
>
> rvm:
>       version:      "rvm 1.6.23 by Wayne E. Seguin
>   (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"
>
> homes:
>       gem:          "not set"
>       ruby:         "not set"
>
> binaries:
>       ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
>       irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
>       gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
>       rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"
>
> environment:
>       PATH:
>   "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/shawntaylorphoto/bin:/"
>       GEM_HOME:     ""
>       GEM_PATH:     ""
>       MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
>       IRBRC:        ""
>       RUBYOPT:      ""
>       gemset:       ""

Note: I'm on OSX 10.6.7

Comment: Add the output of `rvm info` to your question by editing it.

Comment: What's the output of `which gcc`. So you did not install Xcode in `/Developer` like it defaults to?

Comment: Thank Tin man - done that now.

Comment: Dylan, it is in the /Developer folder - I just described that wrong. Have corrected it now:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect XCode needs to be in its default installation location. On all my Macs that has been in `/Developer`.

Also, you don't say what version of the OS you are running, but there are buggy versions of XCode so it helps to have the most current version for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the "Developer Tools" sub-system which is on your OS X install disc.

Comment: Ok I'll do that and report back.